# Problems with JqueryUI Datepicker Date Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have from server side the date like follows

```
 endDate : Mon Nov 07 00:00:00 CET 2011 (Java.util.Date)
 startDate : Fri Feb 04 00:00:00 CET 2011 (Java.util.Date)
```

Now i have two jquery UI datepicker

I want to restrict the two datepickers so that user can select dates only from the above dates.

I saw like u can set the minDate and maxDate for a date picker.

I did some like follows in :

```
$("#startDatePicker").datepicker({
minDate: $.datepicker.formatDate( 'dd.mm.yy',new Date(startDate.getTime())),
maxDate: $.datepicker.formatDate( 'dd.mm.yy',new Date(endDate.getTime())),
...

$("#endDatePicker").datepicker({
minDate: $.datepicker.formatDate( 'dd.mm.yy',new Date(startDate.getTime())),
maxDate: $.datepicker.formatDate( 'dd.mm.yy',new Date(endDate.getTime())),
...
```

But something is wrong. In the start date picker he is showing 2020.? and end datepicker he has disabled everything in the datepicker. I don't understand what is wrong here..?

Answer (score 0):

Add: [jquery-dateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat) jQuery plugin.

Code

```
 var minDate = $.format.date(startDate, "dd/MM/yyyy");

 $("#startDatePicker").datepicker({
    minDate: minDate
    ...
```

Test sample:

```
 <script type="test/javascript">
       alert($.format.date("Wed Jan 13 10:43:41 CET 2010", "dd/MM/yyyy"));
 </script>
```